# Facebook page status update via fb apps in php

Tags: php, facebook

I have been trying to post status to my facebook page through a PHP script which runs on my web server. I have succeeded in posting it via app i.e creating an app and using its app id and secret.

**Here is the code snippet of it:**

```
$pgid="############";
$token="###############################";
$this->tasks = new Facebookclass(array(
  'appId'  => '##########',
  'secret' => '##########',
  'cookie' => true,
));
$post = array('access_token' => $token, 'message' => $message);
try{
  $res = $this->tasks->api('/'.$pgid.'/feed','POST',$post);
} catch (Exception $e){
  echo $e->getMessage();
  die();
}
```

It's working fine and updating the status of my facebook page, but that change/update is only visible only to the admin (ie: me) and not to anyone else who views the page.

If I update status normally by FB logging then it's visible to all, but not the status uploaded via this app.

Comment: hmmmm, disable `Sandbox mode` in your app settings...also maybe when you authorized the app you selected "`only me`"? (not sure if this is related but it's worth to check it)

Comment: Thanks for it:) it works now

also i would like to add link in that message like
$message="<a href='link1'>Download on Android</a> or <a href='link2'>iPhone</a>" but if i am doing this its dumping the html in the status. Any suggestions?

Comment: you are welcome. What was the issue?

Comment: You cannot add html tags to your posts, but there's a link parameter that the `feed` connection accepts, an example can be found in my [tutorial](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-post-a-message-on-the-user-wall-using-facebook-graph-api/33/#using_the_php-sdk).

Comment: ok
can u give me a complete list of parameters allowed?
and can we have two links or two images?

Comment: check the [`user`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) object to know what can be posted. And I don't think you can have two links in the `link` parameter, put you can always put them in the `message` field even though this won't be practical. As for images I don't know.

Comment: How to disable sandbox [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20706322/how-to-disable-sandbox-mode-for-app-in-new-facebook-developer

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it was visible to the admin only was because the Sandbox setting was enabled. Disabling sandbox should make the post visible.