# How to disable Sandbox Mode for app in new Facebook Developer?

Tags: facebook, sandbox, mode

I can not see an option to disable that in the new Developers design!

Answer (score 74):

Its seems they have moved this option to the "Status & Review" section.
When accessing this section you will see this text: Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public? And a button where you can change it to "Yes" or "No".

Comment: Also have in mind that to make the option to publish the app available you have to fill a contact email in the configuration tab. If the button is dissabled maybe there is some request like that on a tooltip.

Comment: i did it. still having issue with posting while logged in with normal user, if i login with developer account, it allow to post feed. Does any one has an idea?

Comment: @HirenDabhi if the app already approved, it will behave the same for all public user, right?

Comment: I have done these steps, and waited overnight just to be sure, but still have the same problem. It works for the admin user, but not for anyone else. Same as @Hiren-Dabhi describes. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 20):

before go to the "Status & Review" option, first you need to go to settings option and add "Contact Email", then go to "Status & Review" When accessing this section you will see this text: Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public? And a button where you can change it to "Yes" or "No".

Comment: the contact mail was the key for me! Without it, button does not appear.

Answer (score 2):

Our app went to the sandbox mode automatically after a while.
We had to fill the '**privacy policy**' url, after that we could disable sandbox mode again.

So make sure you have everything filled in correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Y Solved it in Settings-->Contact Email: type it.
Then go to Status & Review and put it on the Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public? option at top of the page.

Also make sure that the age restrictions +13 and country is not set.