# Automated Posts Made to Facebook Page Via API Can't be Seen by Users

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I recently set up an HTTP poster that uses cURL, PHP and the Facebook API to post to my page's timeline.

The page is a dedicated #nowplaying page for an online radio station, so the auth token and associated facebook app is only for one user, which is myself.

The poster has been working for a few weeks, but I have only just now realised that only I can see the posts, which (as they appear to me) are made 'as the page'. Other page followers can only see a single manual post I made welcoming people to the page.

I know this might be a super user question, but I have checked all relevant page settings, and the fact that they can see manual posts by the page makes me thing it's an API/Token thing.

Q: Why can't my facebook page visitors see my automated posts?

- [Here is my page](https://www.facebook.com/bcnowplaying)
- [Here is what I see, and what I want users to
  see](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zvhm3ck231vld2v/Screen%20Shot%202014-01-21%20at%2008.42.25.png). Note: notice the little world logo on each post indicating that they are public.

Edit: I'm making the post over http at https://graph.facebook.com/{pageID}/feed...

Comment: First of all, check if your Facebook app id you are using to make the posts is out of sandbox mode …

Comment: Just trying to get out of development mode now. I have to submit it for assessment yes? It's asking for some things I'll never need. Like 4 screen shots of a user logging into facebook via my website. I don't need this. All I need is the auth token. Will I be forced to roll out FB login for my website?

Comment: No, you don’t need to submit your app for review.

Comment: It's demanding I show a user screenshot (actually 4). But thanks for your help. I wasn't thinking outside of the sandbox and would never have figured it out. Ha ha.

Comment: Disabling sandbox mode does not require you to upload anything … you don’t have to click on “Start a submission” to save that setting.

Comment: [Got it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20781713/19017810). Thanks again. If you answer (regarding 'Make available to the public') I'll mark it right. I did see that switch but though it meant make the app available to the public to use.